# how to rename files to sub directories using cmd

Tags: powershell, command-line, cmd, robocopy

I have a several levels of folders and these folders contain *.csv files. I need to rename these files in next format:

Source sub-directories with files:

```
C:\Folder1\Folder2\FileName1.csv
C:\Folder1\Folder2\FileName2.csv
...
```

Output:

```
C:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder1_Folder2_FileName1.csv
C:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder1_Folder2_FileName2.csv
...
```

Could you someone help with this?

Thanks

Comment: look up the commands get-childitem and rename-item. When you have problem with writing the code then post the code here and we will help you

Comment: `Get-ChildItem` and using the `$_.Directory` and `$_.Directory.Parent` commands with `Rename-Item` should give you what you want - nobody here will write the whole script for you though, so give it a try and come back when you encounter a specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your questions says "using cmd" but you've tagged this with PowerShell. I think most people will assume you want a PowerShell answer rather than a script that will work in an old-style NT command prompt...

`Get-ChildItem` will build a list of files under a folder, maybe **Folder1** in your case. You can filter for just files ending in ".csv" and move recursively through sub-folders using the `-Recurse` switch.

```
$source_files = Get-ChildItem *.csv -File -Recurse
```

The `$source_files` variable will include the list of files. You will need to loop through this list (hint: use `foreach`) and perform the following:

1. Get the full name of the *directory* that the file is in
2. *Split* this into an array divided by the "\" character
3. *Join* that array up again using the underscore character
4. Rename the file with the folder names at the front

List others have commented, we're not going to write your script, but most people are happy to help people new to PowerShell get going in the right direction. Remember to research what you can!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a batch file solution for this task with the description between main routine at top and subroutine `RenameFile` at bottom.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "C:\Folder1\*.csv" /A-D /B /S 2^>nul') do call :RenameFile "%%I"
endlocal
goto :EOF

rem The DIR command above is executed in a separate command process in
rem backround by command FOR. It outputs an unsorted list of all *.csv
rem file names with full path found in C:\Folder1 or any subdirectory to
rem handle STDOUT. In case of no CSV file found an error message is output
rem by DIR to handle STDERR which is redirected to device NUL to suppress it.

rem Command FOR captures everything written to STDOUT by DIR and processes
rem this output line by line. Each line containing a file name with full
rem path is just passed to the subroutine RenameFile below called by FOR.

rem RenameFile first separates the file name with path into just file name
rem and file path without drive letter and colon. From file path the \ at
rem beginning is removed next before each backslash in file path is replaced
rem by an underscore.

rem Then an environment variable is defined which is the file name with
rem converted file path removed from file name. This is done to check if
rem the CSV file was not already renamed once in the past by prepending
rem the file path to the the file name. Those CSV files having already
rem the file path in file name are skipped on file renaming command.

:RenameFile
set "FileName=%~nx1"
set "FilePath=%~p1"
set "FilePath=%FilePath:~1%"
set "FilePath=%FilePath:\=_%"
call set "TestName=%%FileName:%FilePath%=%%"
if "%TestName%" == "%FileName%" ren %1 "%FilePath%%FileName%"
goto :EOF
```

Please note that this batch file solution as written does not work if any folder in path of a CSV file contains an equal sign in folder name.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `2>nul` whereby the redirection operator `>` must be escaped here by caret character `^` to be interpreted first as literal character by Windows command interpreter on parsing **FOR** command line before the **DIR** command line is executed with `>` without `^` in a separate command process in the background by **FOR**.